# vuejs2: How to pass vuex store to vue-router components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vuex

In case when `vue-router` is not used, store can be passed to child components when declaring `new Vue()`

But I am using both `vue-router` and `vuex`. In this case how can I make `store` available to `components`. For e.g. my `store.js` is typical:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode'
import axios from 'axios'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    jwt: localStorage.getItem('t'),
    endpoints: {
      obtainJWT: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/obtain_token',
      refreshJWT: 'http://0.0.0.0:8000/auth/refresh_token'
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    updateToken(state, newToken){
      localStorage.setItem('t', newToken);
      state.jwt = newToken;
    },
    removeToken(state){
      localStorage.removeItem('t');
      state.jwt = null;
    }
  },
  actions:{
    obtainToken(username, password){
    //commented code
    },
    refreshToken(){
    //commented code
    },
    inspectToken(){
    //commented code
    }
  }
  });
```

My main.js file is as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

import { store } from './store'
console.log(store)
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

And router/index.js file is as below:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'
import Signup from '@/components/signup/Signup'
import store from '../store.js'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: function (resolve) {
        require(['@/components/login/Login.vue'], resolve)
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      name: 'Signup',
      component: Signup
    }
  ]
})
```

Now how can I pass `store` to my `Signup` component. Even though I am passing store in `new Vue()` it is not available in `Signup` component

Answer (score 3):

> I think the problem is that you importing store and you use the `../store.js`,but when you import js file you dont have to use the `.js` so it has to be `import store from '../store'`

**Also you dont have to pass the vuex store in components using vue-router.**
So follow below the installation of vuex store and vue-router!

*Vuex Store:*

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store  = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        propertiesName: 'PropValue'
    },
    getters: {},
    mutations: {},
    actions: {}
});
```

*Vue-Router:*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Page from '@/components/Page.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/Page',
      name: 'Page',
      component: Page,
    },
    //other routes
  ],
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
    if(savedPosition){ //when use press back button will go at the position he was on the page
        return savedPosition
    }
    if(to.hash){ //if has a hash positition to go
        return { selector: to.hash } //go to the page in scrolled Position
    }
    return { x:0, y: 0 } //go to the page in scroll = 0 Position
  }  
})
```

*main.js:*

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import { store } from '../store/store'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

**Note:Doing that,now you have access of router and store in all your components**

*To use the store in your components:*

```
this.$store.state.propertiesName
```

*To use the router in your components:*

```
this.$router.push({name: 'Page'})
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I tried your solution and your doubt about importing is not the issue. I modified the code as you mentioned and `console.log(store)` is still printing `store` object in main.js but `console.log(this.$store)` is printing `undefined` in components. I have edited the question to present exact code, please have a look

Comment: Hi, I found the issue. The store was available since beginning but I was trying console.log(this.$store) in components <script> tag, outside every method. Hence at this time component is not initiated and store was unavailable. Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to help you,but still you dont have to import the store in the router file.Why you importing it?

Comment: Oh...that I forgot to remove! It's not required as you mentioned