# Accessing Vue Store values in Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I need to access a variable from my store in my router. This variable is called 'isAdmin'. Now, when I'm using the following code, I'm getting the initial state (which has the value of 'false'):

```
console.log(store.state.isAdmin)
```

Although I've updated the 'isAdmin' value to 'true' committing an action, the state of 'isAdmin' continues to be as the initial state.

Now, if I console.log the following object:

```
console.log(store.state)
```

I see this:

[image: How to get isAdmin from there?]

My question is: How do I get to the value of isAdmin after I've amended it in my store?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you share the code you're using for the router to use the store?

Comment: This is what I have in the router.js: 
`import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import store from './store'`;

Comment: No, we must know the context in which you're calling `console.log`... The router is not reactive, so you shouldn't expect things to be reactive there. But it will track the changes once a navigation cycle occurs. Edit your answer with the full example.

Comment: Line 37: http://take.ms/XRo8c

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603909/accessing-vuex-state-when-defining-vue-router-routes