# How to properly call vuex getters

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to learn vuex and I've been stuck with this problem for almost an hour and I just want to get the value of `getters.loggedIn` to `true` or `false`:

**auth.js**

```js
const state = {
  token: localStorage.getItem('access_token') || null,
  currentUser: '',
}

const getters = {
  loggedIn(state) {
    if (state.token) {
      console.log('has token')
      return true
    } else {
      console.log('no token')
      return false
    }
  },
}
```

**router.js**

I imported the file to router.js `import storeAuth from "./store/modules/auth";`

and called it like this `const isLoggedIn = storeAuth.getters.loggedIn;`

But the data that I'm getting is not a `boolean`.

How to properly use getters in vuex?

Comment: you should import the store.js config file... not the module, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603909/accessing-vuex-state-when-defining-vue-router-routes) have many examples.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo omg your right its working now. If you can post it as an answer i'll accept it thank you very much.