# How to ensure that my vuex store is available in router

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js, vue-router

Good day am working on a vue project that uses both vue-router and vuex
In the app whenever login is successful, I store the the JWT token in vuex. However im strugling with the following

1) Dynamically show/hide login/logoff buttons in my navbar
2) Access JWT token in vuex store when the routes changes in router.js

So basically i need access to my vuex store in my router and also how to update my navbar component when my vuex state changes (ie when login is successful)

Below is my code. I'll start with **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import App from '../app.vue'
import router from '../router.js'
import store from '../store'

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(Vuetify)

const vuetify = new Vuetify

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        router,
        vuetify,
        store,
        render: h => h(App)         
  })
})
```

Then **router.js**

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Index from './views/index.vue'
import Appointments from './views/appointments.vue'
import CreateAppointment from './views/createAppointment.vue'
import Login from './views/login.vue'
import store from './store'

const router =  new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'root',
            component: Index
        },
        {
            path: '/login',
            name: 'login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/index',
            name: 'index',
            component: Index
        },
        {
            path: '/appointments',
            name: 'appointments',
            component: Appointments,
            props: true,
            meta: { 
                requiresAuth: true
           }
        },
        {
            path: '/create-appointment',
            name: 'create-appointment',
            component: CreateAppointment,
            meta: { 
               requiresAuth: true
           }
        }
    ]
})   

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
      next()
      return
    }    
    next('/login') 
  } else {
    next() 
  }
})

export default router
```

Then comes store which is index.js inside of store folder

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import * as patient from './modules/patient.js'
import * as appointment from './modules/appointment.js'
import * as user from './modules/user.js'
import * as notification from './modules/notification.js'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {},
    modules: {
        user,
        patient,
        appointment,
        notification
    }
})
```

And lastly is my nabar.vue component which is nested in App.vue. Ps i have taken out navigation drawer and bottom navigation to lessen the code.

```
<template>
    <nav>       
    <v-app-bar app dark>
        <v-btn text rounded dark v-on:click='showDrawer = !showDrawer'>
            <v-icon class='grey--text' left>menu</v-icon>
        </v-btn>      
      <v-toolbar-title d-sm-none>
        <span class='font-weight-light'>SASSA</span>      
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>   
      <!-- Log in button  -->
      <v-btn text rounded dark v-on:click='login' v-show='!isLoggedIn'>
        <span>Login</span>
        <v-icon class='grey--text' right>arrow_forward</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <!-- Log out button  -->
      <v-btn text rounded dark v-on:click='logout' v-show='isLoggedIn'>
        <span>Logout</span>
        <v-icon class='grey--text' right>exit_to_app</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </v-app-bar>
    </nav>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex'
    export default {
        data(){
            return {
              activeBtn: 1,
              showDrawer: false,
                links: [                    
                    { title: 'Appointments', icon: 'calendar_today', link: '/appointments'},
                    { title: 'New Appointment', icon: 'event', link: '/create-appointment'}
                ]          
            }
        },
    computed: {
      isLoggedIn() {
        var result = (this.$store.getters['isLoggedIn'] == "true")           
        return result
      },      
      ...mapState(['user'])
    },

    methods: {
      logout() {
        this.$store.dispatch('user/logout')
        .then(() => {
          this.$router.push('/login')
        })
      },
      login() {
        this.$router.push('/login')
      }
    }
    }
</script>
```

This is where i try to access store in router

```
    if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Below is the user.js  module

```
import AxiosService from '../services/AxiosService.js'

export const namespaced = true

export const state = {
    status: '',             
    token:  '',             
    user:  {}               
}

export const mutations = {
    AUTH_SUCCESS(state, payload){       
        state.status = 'logged_on'
        state.token = payload.token
        state.user = payload.user
    },
    LOGG_OFF(state){
        state.status = 'logged_off'
        state.token = ''
        state.user = {}
    }
}

export const actions = {
    login({commit, dispatch}, user){            
        return AxiosService.logon(user)
        .then(response => {
            const token = response.data.auth_token
            const user = response.data.user             
            localStorage.setItem('token',token)
            commit('AUTH_SUCCESS', {token, user})
        })
        .catch(error => {           
            const notification = {
                type: 'error',
                message: 'Invalid Credentials !!!'
            }   
            dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true})
            throw error
        })
    },
    logout({commit}){
        localStorage.setItem('token','')
        commit('LOGG_OFF')
    }
 }

export const getters = {
    isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
    authStatus: state => state.status,
    getUser: state => state.user
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have with navbar? As for router, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603909/accessing-vuex-state-when-defining-vue-router-routes

Comment: So once someone loggs in, vuex gets updated with a jwt token and i want to hide the login button and display the loggout button.

Comment: This should happen if you use `isLoggedIn` in template like you do. Does it not work?

Comment: Look like a problem with `isLoggedIn`. Could you share the module?

Comment: No it doesnt, it keeps displaying the login button. Because the v-show is supposed to work with computed right ?

Comment: Okay let me share the user.js module

Comment: The main issue i'm having is being able to import and use the vuex store inside of the router...because im adding navigation rules and i need to display error notifications

Answer (score 0):

Hey all i managed to fix it.

Problem was because my modules are namepsaced i have to access like this

```
store.getters['user/isLoggedIn']
```

Instead of
    store.user.isLoggedIn

Thanks again. However i still have the issue of the navbar not updating