# Error when i am trying to confirm an email from flask and then redirect to vue route, did i missed something or what approach can i use?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, flask, vue-router

**Flask API for email token validation:**

```
@app.route("/api/v1.0/verify", methods=["GET"])
def confirm_email():
    token = request.args.get('token')
    new_url = 'http://futurex-google-cloud-lab-2.futurex.com.ph:8080'
    register = 'register'
    email_verify = 'verify_email'
    try:
        email = s.loads(token, salt="email-confirm", max_age=300)
        # return {"message": "The token works!"}, 200
        return redirect('{new_url}/{page}'.format(new_url=new_url, page=register), 302)
    except SignatureExpired:
        # return {"message": "The token is expired"}, 403
        return redirect('{new_url}/{page}'.format(new_url=new_url, page=email_verify), 403)
```

**My vue route:**

```
{
        path: "/register",
        component: Register,
        beforeEnter (to, from, next){
            const email_token = window.localStorage.getItem('email_token')
            console.log(email_token)

            if(email_token === '' || email_token === null){
                next('/verify_email')
            }else {
                axios.get('http://futurex-google-cloud-lab-2.futurex.com.ph:5000/api/v1.0/verify?token=' + email_token)
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log(res)
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err)
                        next('/verify_email')
                    })
            } 
        }
    }
```

**And got error when accessing the route:**

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://futurex-google-cloud-lab-2.futurex.com.ph:8080/register' (redirected from 'http://futurex-google-cloud-lab-2.futurex.com.ph:5000/api/v1.0/verify?token=Im5pc3BpYm9wc3VAZW5heXUuY29tIg.XnxCBw.2B47QLF-JBJ5_p16R5m2e6PuEK8') from origin 'http://futurex-google-cloud-lab-2.futurex.com.ph:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
routes.js?7aab:49 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js?ec6c:83)
register:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

My goal is to prevent the user to access the vue route unless the token is valid if i make any sense. I've tried everything but don't know how to fix this. By the way I'm new to flask and vuejs so your help will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move between different Vue routes on your client, not your server. So just move the redirect logic to within your Vue method:

```
methods {
  login: function () {
      axios.post('login', { email:this.email, password:this.password })
        .then( user => {
            this.$store.commit('set_user',user) // for authorisation
            this.$router.push('/account')
         })
        .catch( err => this.message = err )
    },
}
```

If you are redirecting to authorised access only pages you will need to add an authorisation guard to your vue routes on your vue router - see:

[Accessing Vuex state when defining Vue-Router routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603909/accessing-vuex-state-when-defining-vue-router-routes?rq=1)

Comment: Hi, can you please a explain further, my goal is to prevent the user to access the Vue route unless it is valid token. Thanks

Comment: Added a link to my answer which explains the next step.