# How to use vue-router in Vuex module Actions?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I want to do `this.$router.push(path)` inside module file of vuex.
As this is not defined there, how could I perform this.

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42604186/2815635)

Comment: @NikleshRaut seems like the OP want to it the opposite way, accessing the router in Vuex and not the state in routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just import the router and you'll be able to use it, like this:

```
import router from 'path/to/router'

router.push(path)
```

**Why does it work like this:**

In a Vue file, `this` is binded to the Vue object which is why you can use certain methods that are available there like $router or $store.

However in a normal JS file `this` is just binded to the global object that does not contain any of Vue's special functionality, which is why you have to import the router manually.

Comment: Thanks, I could use vuex in router and vice versa.